# Will nodejs' mongodb client will create a new db for me?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

According to tie piece of [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/databases-and-collections/) if I run these upon mongosh:

```
use myDB
db.myNewCollection1.insertOne( { x: 1 } )
```

Will automatically create a `myDb` database and will a collection `myNewCollection1`.

Therefore if upon my nodejs run:

```
const {MongoClient, ServerApiVersion} = require('mongodb');

// Connectionstring
const uri = 'mongodb://root:example@127.0.0.1:27017/';

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    serverApi: {
        version: ServerApiVersion.v1, strict: true, deprecationErrors: true,
    }
});
client.connect({poolSize:10});
const database = client.db('myDb');
const collection = database.collection('myNewCollection1')

collection.updateOne({"var":value})
```

I mean if I run the nodejs code above will automatically create the database `myDb` and collection `myNewCollection1` as would be done via `mongosh`?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty easy thing to test, especially if you already have the code written. I look forward to upvoting an answer from you with the findings

Answer (score 0):

The nodejs driver will always create the collection if one does not already exist when a document is inserted, as the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertOne/#insert-a-document) suggests:

> You can insert a document into a collection using the
> collection.insertOne() method. To insert a document, define an object
> that contains the fields and values that you want to store. If the
> specified collection does not exist, the insertOne() method creates
> the collection.

If you wish to tweak it, for example, make it time-series, cropped or change the default string collation, you should create it manually.